# Unity play sound for every 1 degree rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a dial that rotates with mouse drag. I want to play a crank sound for every one degree of rotation but found it difficult to calc the difference because values less than one if I slowly drag the wheel where if I quickly move the wheel the same distance the sound will play rapidly

So for example

If previous `z` was 3.78645 and the next was 3.983 then no sound. If it is 3.983 to 4.189 then a sound would fire.

```
private onDrag(){
    ...
    var diff = prevValue - 360 * knobValue;

    if (diff > 1) {
       AudioManager.Instance.PlaySfx(crankSound);
    }

    prevValue = 360 * knobValue;
}
```

Comment: What type are prevValue and knobValue

Comment: Convert your floating values to ints, let it truncate the floating point, it would convert 3.78 and 3.98 to 3, and 4.1 to 4, You can even use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html to do this for you to be safe, then if your diff being an int is >= to 1 it should play.

Comment: @Eddge that still wouldn't solve the OP's problem as he is updating prevValue every onDrag call, meaning it is still dependant on the amount of movement in that single drag (read he's getting alot of sounds when moving the knob fast, but none when slowly). Converting from float to int also adds extra overhead that isn't necessary

Comment: @remy_rm not sure how removing the floating point value altogether wouldn't solve the problem, nor can we say it won't until its tried.  I did read it, and I read his response on several answers, he clearly states it plays for the slightlest decimal change, removing the decimal from the equation and working with solid whole numbers seems like a reasonable attempt.

Comment: @Eddge I didn't mean it can't be done the way you're suggesting. But it would take more than "just" truncating to floating point values and seeing if the `diff >= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `prevValue` only after the difference has been greater than one. Else it will only check if the amount of degrees in that single `OnDrag` frame was bigger than zero, instead of checking over a multitude of drags.

fixing this is quite simple, only set `prevValue` after `diff` has been bigger than one. There is also no need to multiply the knobValue by 360, if `knobValue`  is equal to the `transform.localEulerAngle` of the knob you are turning. if your `knobValue` is in radians you need to multiply it with `Mathf.Rad2Deg` first.

Here is a working example:

```cs
float prevValue;
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    //Your logic for turning the knob 

    //Here i'm assuming that knobValue is the value of the z rotation of your knob in degrees (its localEularAngle)
    var diff = prevValue - knobValue;

    //Take the absolute value of diff so it works for turning both ways
    if (Mathf.Abs(diff) > 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("difference is bigger than 1, playing sound");
        AudioManager.Instance.PlaySfx(crankSound);

        //Again assuming knobValue is in degrees
        prevValue = knobValue; //Only update the prevvalue if the difference was bigger than 1
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Value was smaller than 1, not playing sound: " + diff);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm a bit newer so this might sound stupid, wouldn't it be possible to use the actual transform rotations of the gameobject? Have a for loop for -180 to 180 and if its equal to that then play the audio sound.

I'm just throwing an idea out, I don't know how demanding that loop would be or if there is a quick way.

edit: I would comment this but I need 2 more rep to comment

Comment: I would need the sound to play for every one degree of rotation so if the dial was move 180 then the sound would have played 180 times. My problem is that the sound play thousands of time because of the decimal places.

Comment: So doesn't it playing 360 times for 360 degrees solve that problem? I could see that working.

Comment: @KeithPower What is stoping you from converting the degree to an integer value, then checking the difference and only playing that many times?

Comment: @Eddge That was my same thought process, if you only check for whole numbers then it wouldnt do it for each decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the Game Development Stack Exchange, you will find more Unity knowledge there

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

if you would like for the sound to play at any given point when the know passes a tick. then i would recommend just placing a check in the update loop. so that the tick will definitely sound at the same time as passing the tick.
or you could place lil colliders on the tick marks. that is a sure fire way for this to work.

Oh. if you are new to game dev or unity. please make sure you are not checking the rotation of the knob on its local rotation variable directly. that is a Quaternion. and its 0-1 value does not correspond to being multiplied by 360. 
instead call

```
 localRotation.Euler()
```

to get a vector3 which contains the degrees of rotation.